# Display Type of Triangle Based on Angles

Tags: c++, if-statement, visual-studio-2013

```
            else if ((ang1 != ang2) && (ang2 != ang3) && (ang1 != ang3))
                {
                    if ((ang1 = 90) || (ang2 = 90) || (ang3 = 90))
                    {
                        cout << "This is a Right, Scalene Triangle!";
                    }
                    else if ((ang1 < 90) && (ang2 < 90) && (ang3 < 90))
                    {
                        cout << "This is an Acute, Scalene Triangle!";
                    }
                    else if ((ang1 > 90) || (ang2 > 90) || (ang3 > 90))
                    {
                        cout << "This is an Obtuse, Scalene Triangle!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // you shouldn't get here
                    }
                }
```

No matter what I put in for ang1, ang2, or ang3; it'll say it is a right, scalene triangle. I don't understand why it is ignoring the second else-if statements parameters.

Comment: You are using `=` instead of `==` in `if ((ang1 = 90) || (ang2 = 90) || (ang3 = 90))`

Comment: `(ang1 = 90) || (ang2 = 90) || (ang3 = 90)` will always be true. You are assigning not comparing

Answer (score 2):

You should use the equal operator `==` not the assignment operator `=`.